# Unable to rectify Matlab error - 'Undefined function 'A5_mn' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab, function

I'm writing a code for the thermodynamic design of a turbojet. A part of my code is as follows:

```
if pi_N > pi_CR
    disp('Flow through propulsive nozzle is Choked');
    T5 = T04 * (1/(gamma_G + 1));   %Temperature at nozzle exit
    p5 = p04/pi_CR; %Pressure at nozzle exit
    rho5 = p5/(R*T5);   %Air density at Nozzle Exit
    Ca5 = sqrt(gamma_G * R * T5);   %Air velocity at nozzle exit
    A5_mN = 1 / (rho5 * Ca5);   %Area of flow divided by mass flow rate in the nozzle
    Fs = (Ca5 - Ca1) + A5_mn(p5 - pa);  %Specific Thrust
end
```

So when I run the code, I get an error-- Undefined function 'A5_mn' for input arguments of type 'double'. I know this means that the variable 'A5_mn' is being treated as a function and not as a variable. But I, for the life of me, am not able figure how to rectify this.

Comment: You variable is `A5_mN` but then you try use it as `A5_mn`. **MATLAB is case sensitive**. If you really do have a function called `A5_mn` then firstly you need to fix your naming convention because that's very confusing and secondly you probably have not put it in the active directory.

Comment: I think you should delete this question

Comment: Yes how do I do that??

Comment: If there is no *delete* link under the question tags for you (which is possible as it might be reputation based) then *flag* it for a moderator to delete (also under the question tags)